# Restler 2: When calling index.php, display error 404

Tags: php, rest, frameworks, restler

I am new to Restler 2.0
I trying to create an API, http://exampe.com/api/index.php/lbs/hello/123456 and it return success result
But when i put http://exampe.com/api/index.php/lbs/getloc/123456, it return fail. 
Anyone know what does it happen?

Result:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
  }
}
```

Below are the code:

index.php

```
require_once 'restler/restler.php';
require_once 'classes/lbs.php';

$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('LBS');
$r->addAPIClass('Say');
$r->handle();
```

lbs.php

```
class LBS {
    function getloc($to) {
        return $to;
    }

    function hello($to) {
        return $to;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the file containing the class `Say` you added via `addAPIClass` method. Your index file should be something like below

```
require_once 'restler/restler.php';
require_once 'classes/lbs.php';
require_once 'classes/say.php';

$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('LBS');
$r->addAPIClass('Say');
$r->handle();
```

Comment: oops, eventually actually i had put that, but the error still the same:

 require_once 'restler/restler.php';
 require_once 'classes/lbs.php';
 require_once 'classes/sms.php';
 require_once 'classes/say.php';
 
 $r = new Restler();
 $r->addAPIClass('LBS');
 $r->addAPIClass('Say');
 $r->handle();

Comment: Now I see the urls you are trying, I think the url should be one of the following http://exampe.com/api/index.php/lbs/getloc/123456 or http://exampe.com/api/index.php/lbs/loc/123456. (e.g. I used a function defined as postHello, and I used HTTP POST method to call the url http://exampe.com/api/index.php/lbs/hello/123456. Worked for me. Thought you could try this).

Comment: I used "getloc" and also "hello", function details are same for both, but "hello" is working, "getloc" is not working

Comment: did you try "loc" as I mentioned in second link?

Comment: It seems Restler uses a naming convention so that the "get" part of "getloc" represents GET method, and the rest is the function to quote in url ("loc"). Read [here](http://help.luracast.com/restler/examples/_006_crud/readme.html)